# Looking for a cheap cellular modem chipset + GPS

Tags: gps, cellphone, integrated-circuit

I'm looking for advice about available cellular modem chipsets, my main concerns being power consumption followed reliability & then by weight/size.  It can be the worst-performing chipset in the world for all I care as long as I can transfer large amounts of data (up to 100MB or more every couple of weeks) reliably over a period of 6-15 hours (so a very low throughput is perfectly acceptable as long as it won't overheat and die while being active for that long).

I'm looking for suggestions as to brands (the only one I can really find is the 3G chipsets by broadcomm), pricing (I need up to 1,000 or more of these), carrier information (such as suggestions on how to go about talking to a carrier about adding 1,000 intermittent devices to their network?) and any nuances or general suggestions that people have.

Also, integrated GPS is a definite plus, as long as I can kill power to the GPS when necessary.  Otherwise I'm also looking at stand-alone GPS modules.

Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic and will be closed.

Comment: okay, how is it off topic?  Should I post this on a different stackexchange site?  I'm trying to find a chipset for an EE project, figured this was the best place to do so :)

Comment: It's nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: @Leon Heller how does this not have to do with electronics design?  If this is off topic then every question asking about what type of capacitor i should use or what op amp i should use is off topic.

Comment: @cwolves what frequencies / carriers do you need to support?  You generally will need a separate GPS unit.  Also are you looking for modules or individual chips?  1000 units is really nothing in the cell world so yours probably stuck with modules.

Comment: @Mark - I'm open to any carrier(s), and may need to start looking at other carriers in countries on the Pacific Rim (Mexio, South America, Canada, Japan, Australia, etc) within a couple of years, so ideally GSM.  The extra carriers are far-off at this point, however, so I'm not really worried about it.  As for frequency, I'm looking for longest-distance often line-of-sight (or close to it) connections, so probably 1900mhz GSM over 850mhz.  Unless the power difference between the two is significant, then 850...

Comment: @cwolves - you should probably integrate the information in your comment back into the question.  Also, this question is one which treads a very fine line of bad shopping vs. market research problems (See the [[shopping](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping)] meta-tag, especially [this answer](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/475/489#489), and [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more information).  If you see anything on those pages that gives you an idea for improving this question, please do so!

Comment: @cwolves You need to at least determine a technology and frequency bands needed.  Depending on country and some times carrier, different frequencies are used.  For instance for GSM in North America, Australia and parts of South America 850Mhz and 1900Mhz are used.  In much of Europe 900Mhz and 1800Mhz are used.  In some countries use all 4 frequencies and still other countries don't use GSM at all (Japan).  Additionally you need to consider other issues that can differ between carriers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cellular modem chip will generally not also contain the GPS, the GPS receiver in cell phones is often built into the system SoC (Nexus One) or is an external component (iphone 4).

Either way, its not cost effective to build a modem from a chipset for 1000 units, you'd probably have trouble just getting access to the parts to do so, 1000 units isn't even on qualcomm's radar.  Not only that but implementing the chipset is very complex and requires access to proper EMI/RF testing equipment and facilities.

Instead look for cellular modem modules.  [Examples.](http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/68)

Some of these will have on board GPS and some you can program to the on-board CPU if your application isn't compute intensive.  If you need external processing you normally communicate with them via a serial bus using a modified AT command set.

For 1000 units obviously skip talking to sparkfun and go straight to the module manufacturer, there are many out there.

As mentioned in my comments you do need to figure out what technology / bands you need to support.  The likely best option is a quad-band GSM module which should work in most places.  There are some exceptions, for instance GSM isn't used in Japan or South Korea at all.  Other countries may have some GSM support but CDMA is more commonly used.  There are modules out there that support multiple frequencies as well as multiple modes such as GPRS/GSM/CDMA/HSPA but the more frequencies and modes the module supports the more expensive it gets.  It may make more sense to design the device such that you can drop in whatever modem you want (within reason).

Talk to whatever local carrier you can find where the devices are geing installed to get the required SIMs.  For ~1000 lines you should be talking to someone at the corporate level, not the average guy at a local store.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a module very similar to http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9533 before. (Sparkfun doesn't carry the one I used.) They're pretty straightforward to use, but had some goofy power supply requirements (13.2VDC IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

There actually a MTK solution LinkIt ONE which you can get from this site:
http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/LinkIt-ONE-p-2017.html